# Ruby - Substituting whitespace in all array elements with every non-whitespace character

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex, string, gsub

I am 99% certain that this question hasn't been asked before, so here goes.

Suppose we have an array of strings

```
strings = ['first string', 'second string', 'third string']
```

I would like to create a new massive array where I substitute the **whitespace character** in each of the three elements with each of the non-whitespace characters(letters, numbers, symbols).

It would look something like this.

```
new_array = ['firstastring', 'secondastring', 'thirdastring', 'firstbstring', .. 
'first1string', 'seond1string', .. 'third^string', ...]
```

The count of the new array should be the number of elements in the original array(3) multiplied by the number of non-whitespace characters in Ruby

One possible solution would be this

```
new_array = []
/[\S]/.each do |character|
  strings.each do |string|
    new_array.gsub(string, character)
  end
end
```

I understand in regex the \S expression refers to any non-whitespace character so I figured that would be the best thing to use.

I am still a beginner in Ruby so I appreciate any help.

From my understanding of Ruby the solution most likely involves an each loop.

**Update**
Sorry guys, look like you can't call the **each** method on the **regex** class. I have another idea.

```
characters_array = (0..9).to_a.map(&:to_s) + ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a + 
["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "-", "_", "+", "=", "`", "~", 
":", ";", ",", ".", "?", "/"]

new_array = []
characters_array.each do |character|
  strings.each do |string|
    new_array.gsub(string, character)
  end
end
```

This is just an idea though.

Comment: I think you misunderstood regular expressions. You cannot call `each` on `/[\S]/`. Regular expressions are for searching and replacing in text, not for describing datasets. What you are trying to do could be achieved quite easily by iterating over the array and an array of the non-whitespace characters. However, I have no idea where you could get an array with all non-whitespace characters. For all letters you can do `('a'..'z').to_a`, but that is hardly enough I guess.

Comment: Thanks, I will update the post, for another idea I have

Comment: What is the set of non-whitespace characters you wish to use? Do you want to include all the unicode characters? Your first step is to define carefully what that set of characters is. Then use that set of characters to substitute in.

Comment: I thought all non-whitespace characters were just numbers, letters and symbols. I created an array with those characters just now.

Comment: @DarkMouse, I'm curious about your use case. Most certainly there's an alternate solution that would not require you to create an array that is 99+% redundant. Care to provide some context?

Comment: Right, I'm trying to create an effective language filter. I provided this, as just an example. And the reason I asked this question was actually to reduce redundancy in the code I already had. That's why I thought of using each blocks.

Comment: Dark, note you could generate `characters_array` like this: `([*(33..126)] - [34, 39, 60, 62, 91, 92, 93, 123, 124, 125]).map(&:chr)`.

Comment: now that I think about it, would it be more efficient if I used symbols instead of strings in my strings array? Or would that not be possible since strings are immutable so I couldn't call those methods on them?

Comment: For language filtering, I would explore [levenshtein distance](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?q=levenshtein) rather than creating a hardcoded massive array. Please look into other possible NLP solutions in Ruby, they'll be a lot more powerful than a roll-your-own solution.

Comment: Thank you Mark Thomas. I'll take a look at that. It will probably be more efficient too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you could do that:

```
strings = ['first string', 'second string', 'third str ing']
subs = %w[0 a ^]
  #=> ["0", "a", "^"]

strings.product(subs).map { |e,c| e.gsub(/\s/,c) }
  #=> ["first0string", "firstastring", "first^string",
  #    "second0string", "secondastring", "second^string",
  #    "third0str0ing", "thirdastraing", "third^str^ing"]
```

or

```
subs.product(strings).map { |c,e| e.gsub(/\s/,c) }
 #=> ["first0string", "second0string", "third0str0ing",
 #   "firstastring", "secondastring", "thirdastraing",
 #   "first^string", "second^string", "third^str^ing"]
```

depending on the order you prefer.

Comment: Hi Cary, I think you made a mistake in your output. In the third string modification, you are substituting twice(including once with a non-whitespace character. Other than that, it looks perfect

Comment: Dark, that was intentional. :-) As you see, I inserted an extra space in `"third string"` in your array `strings`. That was to show what effect that would have.

Comment: I see, that was my bad. I didn't notice your strings array.

Answer (score 1):

You can get you array using [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [`flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map):

```
new_array = characters_array.flat_map do |character|
  strings.map do |string|
    string.gsub(' ', character)
  end
end
```